# Appending image in div of repeater form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I know why this problem is due to `class` I have tried  from accessing `ID` of div but I am not been able to get the desired output. I have a repeater `MovieRating` and In data source of MovieRating I have:

```
         SourceName                Rating
          abc                       3.5
          xyz                        2
          mno                        4
```

and my html is as follows

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="MovieRatingRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MovieRatingRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <div>
           <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SourceName")%>&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <div class="RatingMovie">
             </div>
             <br />
             <span id="MovieRating_<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SourceName")%>">
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Rating")%>
              </span>
          /div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

I am appending `img` tag from jquery like this

```
          function pageLoad(sender, args) {

        $("[id*=MovieRating_]").each(function (index, value) {

            if ($(value).text() > 4.5 && $(value).text() <= 5.0) {
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');

                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
            if ($(value).text() > 3.5 && $(value).text() <= 4.5) {

                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
            if ($(value).text() > 2.5 && $(value).text() <= 3.5) {

                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
            if ($(value).text() > 1.5 && $(value).text() <= 2.5) {

                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
            if ($(value).text() > 0 && $(value).text() <= 1.5) {

                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/FilledStar.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
            if ($(value).text() == 0.0) {
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
                var img = $('<img id=‘dynamic’>');
                img.attr('src', 'images/Star.gif');
                img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
            }
        });
    }
```

now in case of class Getting all stars in all fields of `abc,mno,xyz` and In case of ID I am getting all stars are appending in a single place meaning first place. I am new to jquery/javascript and I dont have idea to do. Any answer are surely appretiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this jquery

```
     $(value).parent().find('#RatingMovie').prepend(img);
```

in place of

```
     img.appendTo('.RatingMovie');
```